# Check for a value in many child nodes in firebase real-time database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, children

I want to retrieve the text 'Private Group' from the child 'group' IF the child 'contacts' has the value '9aIMkiMa0bSuMLjUk3R5bLpnoQS2'. I also want to check for the same value from the other child nodes of the parent child 'questions posts'. I have struggled with it but in vain. This is the code that I have been using, but It has only produced errors.

```
final DatabaseReference groupsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions posts");
    Query query = groupsRef.orderByChild("group").orderByChild("contacts");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            arrayList.clear();
          if (snapshot.exists() && snapshot.hasChild(onlineUserId)){
              arrayList.add(groupsRef.getKey().toString());
              arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

This is the image of the database structure
[image]

Comment: The child "Private Group", is fixed?

Comment: No, in the other nodes, it can be different. It is a value typed by a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Firebase query operates on a flat list of nodes, and can only contain a single unknown key.

From what I can tell you have at least two levels of unknown keys (`-MH...Ez12`, and `9alMk....QS2`) and possibly three (`Private Group`). There is no way to query this structure with a database query, and you will need to come up with a different data structure to allow your use-case.

For example, if you want to allow finding the posts for a given contact ID, consider storing exactly that relationship:

```
"contactsToPosts": {
  "$contactId": {
    "$postId": true
  }
}
```

For more on this sort data modeling trade-off, see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)